# How to simulate 'position:fixed' behavior on Flexbox-aligned sidebar

Tags: html, css, layout, web-deployment, flexbox

As it was already answered ([How can I have a position: fixed; behaviour for a flexbox sized element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29036231/how-can-i-have-a-position-fixed-behaviour-for-a-flexbox-sized-element)) absolutely/fixed positioned boxes are taken out of the normal flow of Flexbox-aligned elements. But how can I at least simulate `position: fixed` behavior of, say, `width: 300px; height: 100vw` element?

Here is a demo (http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGmmzR) of initial layout with sidebar on the left and content block on the right. I would like `nav` act like `position: fixed` element following user's scroll across the page. I know how to do it without Flexbox. In the first place I would consider pure CSS solution without using JavaScript. Thank you!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

**Edit:**

A solution that somehow feels less hacky could be to make the container (`.wrapper`) as tall as the screen, and only add scrolling to the main `<section>` element:

```
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
}

section {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

http://codepen.io/Sphinxxxx/pen/WjwbEO

**Original answer:**

You could simply put everything inside `<nav>` in a wrapper (here: `nav-wrapper`), and then fix that wrapper:

```
...
.nav-wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; left: 0;
}

<nav role="navigation">
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
        ...
    </div>
</nav>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PqXYGM

Comment: This is very correct and obvious solution. I should really have some rest next time before working. Thank you!

Comment: This will only work if the nav is at one of the edges, because `position: fixed` positions relative to the _viewport_. So this won't help if, like me, you're trying to fix a nav inside a centered flex container.

Comment: @VickyChijwani - What would that layout look like? Do you have a demo?

Comment: @Sphinxxx sorry, I don't have a demo. But I ultimately went with an edge-positioned fixed div anyway; ran out of alternatives.

Comment: @SudarP - I don't have a Safari browser, but it's just basic [flexbox](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) behavior, so I assume it does.

Comment: Flex solution works but with overflow property the content scrolling position is broken on refresh (position not remembered).

Comment: @Burrich I used a flex layout similar to the edited solution in this answer. css-tricks.com references a simple JavaScript and local storage solution from a Twitter post (https://twitter.com/hakimel/status/1262337065670316033) for the remembering the scroll position of a sidebar div (or any div). https://css-tricks.com/memorize-scroll-position-across-page-loads/. See the reader comments for recommended modifications to the code in the tweet.